# Switch and Forms

Tags: php, html, forms

I have stared at this code for an hour and can't figure this out to save my life.
maybe I need more coffee

I'm creating a switch register page but every time I submit the form it refreshes the default page heres the code cut down extensively.

```
include("../tools/config.php");
session_start();

switch($_GET['action']){

case "joinb":
addmember($member);
break;

default:
register($user);
break;
}



function register($user){
echo "
<form method='post'>
data blah blah
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='joinb'>
<input type='submit' class='button' name='submit' value='Create Account'>
</form>
";
}

function addmember($member){
insert mysql function
}
```

Comment: Where do `$member` and `$user` come from? Also, why is `$user` even an argument to `register`? It's never used

Comment: Fixed my issues and all is working. Didn't know I needed to change the values to $_POST[username] and what not. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're POSTing the form so `$_GET['action']` will not be populated. I would drop the `switch` and use...

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'joinb') {
    addmember($member);
} else {
    register($user);
}
```

Comment: thanks this also redirects me but I think the problem I'm having now is all me thanks!

Comment: Submitting a HTML Form via the standard Submit button will always redirect you. If you don't want to do this, you must learn to [use AJAX to submit a post](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/).

Comment: @HeikkiU I think they mean an actual redirect (via *Location* header) which probably appears in the `addmember` function. A standard POST request is not a redirect

Comment: @Phil You're right, of course, it's not a redirect, but a POST request. But it might look like a redirect if the same script outputs different things on the screen. After all, the OP said: "every time I submit the form it refreshes the default page" And then: "this also redirects me".

Comment: Would there be a reason my data isn't carrying over? Normally I don't have a problem with forms but this ones got me.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitted with `POST` method, so you should check `$_POST['action']` instead of `$_GET['action']`

Comment: this does redirect me but it doesn't carry over the data

Comment: thanks I believe the problem I'm experiencing now is all me Thanks!